# How to take a returned JSON list and make the data useable in my program by identifying list headers to refer to

Tags: python

Sorry if this seems simple but I'm relatively new to this. I'm looking to take a returned JSON list from a stock API and have the program identify column headings in the list and be able to return the values under that heading for use in subsequent queries. What is the best way to do this? I'm assuming I have to identify the column headings myself?

Here is an example of the list returned and exported to text. I've put the start of the file/list and the end.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "symbol": "AACG",
      "name": "ATA Creativity Global",
      "currency": "USD",
      "exchange": "NASDAQ",
      "mic_code": "XNMS",
      "country": "United States",
      "type": "Depositary Receipt"
    },  <----beginning of list --- end of list ----->  
    {
       "symbol": "ZYXI",
       "name": "Zynex Inc",
       "currency": "USD",
       "exchange": "NASDAQ",
       "mic_code": "XNGS",
       "country": "United States",
       "type": "Common Stock"
    }
  ],
  "status": "ok"
}
```

Not quite sure where to start.

Comment: It depends on where you want to stick this data. For instance, using a dataframe (and assuming this data is stored in variable `data`) you do: `df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])` It will recognize headers and build the dataframe with that one line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're standing in this problem, your question seems you're unable to get the data from the API, in which case you have to install and use [python requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

On the other hand, your question seems you are stuck with the data headers that, since it is a json data structure, we are talking about a list of dictionaries in python, and you can get the keys of the dictionaries like this

```
headers = json_retrieved_from_the_api["data"][0].keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.  Took me 2 days and I feel like a complete idiot but I think it's partially due to the fact that I need to remember that Python has a lot of modules that do a lot of the heavy lifting for you even if what it's doing is a bit esoteric.

Here is the code that returns the JSON data that I previously exported to a .json file basically a text file) and puts up the headings and the data under the headings perfectly.  I was too concerned with writing something that would pull out the little bit of data before and after the main array/tuple of data which Pandas does automatically for you. I haven't rubber-duck explained my code to myself yet as I'm about to do but this works.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('companies_on_nasdaq.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])

print(df)
```

Comment: I didn't figure it out on my own of course, many kudos to JNevill above.